# Deploying to iOS 3.0 with XCode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment

Does anyone know where I can get a simple project template for deploying apps to iOS 3.0 while using XCode 4.4?

edit:

Or any other way to create apps with a deployment target of 3.2 or lower with XCode 4.4?

edit: And what is the current minimum deployment target the AppStore allows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post. They are doing what you require. I hope this helps.

[Here is a link to a post that will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075161/ios-3-x-support-in-xcode-4)