# Unable to run my code on xcode 4.5 using device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am facing this issue on xcode 4.5 while installing my application on device.
Its working perfect on simulator and xcode 3.2.5.
Any help?

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/mymac/Downloads/revmob-ios-sdk'
ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

These are exact lines i am seeing there.

Answer (score 1):

After spending 6 hours web search , I just deleted lxml2 framework from my frameworks list and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're using a device with an old version of iOS. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075161/ios-3-x-support-in-xcode-4) is a great answer that documents how you can use a newer version of Xcode for older versions of iOS.

Comment: Well my deployment target is 4.3 and iOS version of iPhone is 5.1.

Comment: Alright, check if the AdSupport framework is being linked correctly. Go to the target settings > Build Phases > Link binary With Libraries. From there, try re-adding AdSupport.framework.

Comment: These are lines  at the end.ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/mymac/Downloads/revmob-ios-sdk'
ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Try linking libxml2 using the same steps I mentioned. Also, it looks like you're using RevMod SDK. According to their [website](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios), you should also link 'StoreKit.framework' and 'SystemConfiguration.framework'.