# How to make the application for all version in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am beginner in iPhone.

I want to make the iPhone app that compatible for all iPhone versions like 3 and above.

Please help me What to set in the project to make it compatible to all version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set the "Deployment Target" to a particular version of iOS, but otherwise to make your app compatible with versions above 3, you will have to *only* work with the iOS 3 APIs.

Comment: If i set the Deployment Target to 3 then it will run on the all the iphone version?

Comment: In the Target Deployment there is no version 3 in Xcode 4. It only displaying the 4 and above version. How can i get the version 3 also

Comment: See George Sachin's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the deployment target in the target summary.

**Edit**: Xcode 4.5.x only supports iOS 4.3 and later so you can't support iOS versions below it.

**Edit 2:** If you are using and old version of Xcode this might be helpful for you. [iOS 3.x support in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075161/ios-3-x-support-in-xcode-4)

But you should think twice before writing an application that targets iOS4 and above.
Targeting to old versions of iOS means that you must not use any of the API's of the next iOS versions such as ARC and auto layout. As a result your code will be harder to maintain and some features would be impossible to implement.

Before going on with it, think about how many users will you satisfy by supporting iOS4. Read these thousand words from apple and then decide for yourself

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer..In the Target Deployment there is no version 3 in Xcode 4. It only displaying the 4 and above version. How can i get the version 3 also –

Comment: You can't if you want to use Xcode 4. You will need to use an older Xcode version if you want to target iOS 3 or older. The latest OS version supported by the first generation iPod touch and first generation iPhone was 'iPhone OS 3.2.x'.

Comment: okay. My Xcode version is 4.2 but will it support  supports iOS 4.3 and later

Comment: I edited my answer again

Comment: Builds may work with iOS 6 and 7, but it won't give you a warning when you use a method/class which is outdated. For ex.: the UUID method, you will just get rejected from the App Store, but the app will work on device. But there may be more problems in future iOS version like iOS 7.

Comment: okay. Please suggest me what target deployment should i choose that will be best and app will not reject by apple

Comment: This is a personal opinion but I wouldn't target anything below iOS5 unless i had really important reasons.

Comment: So I am settings to ios 5 is it ok now..

Comment: Last question please confirm I am settings to ios 5 then it will run above 5 not below the version 5

Comment: I absolutely confirm :D