# Update an iOS app in the apple store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have updated my app in the apple store and I have put that it is available for iOS 5 and later.

Can I modify it and make it available to iOS 4 and later ?

If I reject the new app, can my users download the old one ?

thank for your response,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one app available (per name, per application id) for sale on the store at one time.  The app store can't sell one app that works only with iOS 5 & newer (i.e. with Storyboards) AND an older one that works with iOS 4 & newer.  So you need to decide which iOS versions you want to support and then submit your update.

Here's a related question that might offer some helpful hints for you:

[Minimum iOS target version that Apple accepts in AppStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842178/minimum-ios-target-version-that-apple-accepts-in-appstore)

Comment: "If you are confident you are NOT using any iOS 5 features (e.g. storyboards), then just mark your update for "iOS 4 & newer" and your (single app) update should be okay." please can you explain me how to do this , thnks

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully make things a bit more clear.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iPad/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/15-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html